# ArrayList different method's scope

Tags: java, arraylist, scope

I have a problem with the code below. I'm getting different results base on where the line  `list = new ArrayList<InClass>();` is declared. In place `//B` but everything works fine when I add it to `//A` and I cannot understand the difference. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ArrayListOne {
private ArrayList<InClass> list;
private InClass in;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayListOne a = new ArrayListOne();
    a.readFile();
}

public void readFile() {
    //A
    /**
     * adding "list = new ArrayList<InClass>();"
     * getting all 4 lines of test.txt
     */
    try {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            assignToObject(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    readObject();
}


public void assignToObject(String s) {
    //B
    /**
     * adding "list = new ArrayList<InClass>();"
     * getting just last line of test.txt
     */
    InClass n = new InClass(s);
    list.add(n);
    System.out.println(list.size());
}

public void readObject() {
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        in = list.get(i);
        System.out.println(in.stTest);
    }
}

//inner class
public class InClass {
    String stTest;
    public InClass(String s) {
        stTest = s;
    }
}
}
```

the `test.txt` has 3 lines. in `//A`, I'm getting all three lines (what I want) but in `//B` I just get the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to see the difference if you "inline" `assignToObject()` by copy-pasting the contents of `assignToObject()` to the proper place in `readFile()`:

```
public void readFile() {

    // B
    // list = new ArrayList<InClass>();

    try {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Here is where assignToObject() was //

            // B
            // list = new ArrayList<InClass>();

            InClass n = new InClass(line);
            list.add(n);
            System.out.println(list.size());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    readObject();
}
```

Now think about if you put `list = new ArrayList<InClass>()` in `A` and `B`.

If you declare `list = new ArrayList<InClass>()` at `A` (i.e. inside `readFile()`), the statement will be executed *once* -- when `readFile()` is called in `main()`. So you'll end up with *one* `ArrayList` containing everything you need.

However, if you declare `list = new ArrayList<InClass>()` at `B` (i.e. inside `assignToObject()`), you'll get a **new** `list` for every line you read (i.e. every time you call `assignToObject()`). This means that every iteration you'll end up with a *new* `ArrayList` that *only contains the most recently read line*. The `ArrayList` containing the previous line was thrown away, as the reference that used to point to it now points to a new object.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Thank you very much